# group same rows on all selected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets which I frequently have to add a couple of rows in the same place on all of them (All the sheets have a similar format). Adding the rows is easy as I can just select multiple sheets however I also need to group the rows but grouping doesn't work when selecting multiple sheets. The code I have so far only groups the first sheet although does select all.

```
Sub Group_Rows()

Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("Net Rev", "PAP", "EST", "DLC", "COP", "CPPF", "Fixed Expenses", "OI", "Int HO by title",)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Net Rev", "PAP", "EST", "DLC", "COP", "CPPF", "Fixed Expenses", "OI", "Int HO by title")).Select
Rows("50:50").Group

End Sub
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What rows are you trying to group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you want to group a single row, but here's the code that will do it..

```
Sub Group_Rows()
    Dim myArray() As String, wsName As Variant

    myArray = Split("Net Rev, PAP, EST, DLC, COP, CPPF, Fixed Expenses, OI, Int HO by title", ", ")

    For Each wsName In myArray
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Rows(50).Group
    Next wsName
End Sub
```

Comment: If i've answered your question, could you mark this as the answer? Thanks!